# how to save javascript blob wav file on server side with node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, upload, wav, getusermedia

I'm trying to use the **getusermedia** API to record the microphone on client side in order to upload the result as a wave file server side.

I found a code that creates a blob and downloads it as a wave file client side and it looks like this :

```
var blob = new Blob ( [ view ], { type : 'audio/wav' } );

// let's save it locally
var url = (window.URL || window.webkitURL).createObjectURL(blob);
var link = window.document.createElement('a');
link.href = url;
link.download = 'output.wav';
var click = document.createEvent("Event");
click.initEvent("click", true, true);
link.dispatchEvent(click);
```

This works fine but now i'm wondering what would be the best way to upload this "blob" to the server while I'm using **node.js** and **socket.io**.

I actually read a lot of stuff around the web and i found some similar questions but i'm a bit confused.
Should I use something like binary.js (it doesn't seem easy associated with socket.io), or socket.io-stream ? or should I just use a post method maybe with something like node-formidable ?

I will probably find a solution if i keep on playing around with pieces of code but I would really appreciate if someone could help me to find a clean and easy way to solve this! :)

Comment: you can just do a form post.  ive done it that way and it works fine.

Comment: ajax can .send(theBlob) to node